# Event not fired in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an overlay for my modal. When someone clicks on the overlay, the modal should be toggled. In my `mounted()` method I have the following code:

```
const overlay = document.querySelector(".modal-overlay");

overlay.addEventListener("click", this.toggleModal);

var closemodal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-close");
for (var i = 0; i < closemodal.length; i++) {
  closemodal[i].addEventListener("click", this.toggleModal);
}
```

I have added the template below

```
   <template> <divclass="modal pointer-events-none fixed w-full h-full top-0 left-0 flex items-center justify-center">
<div ref="overlay" class="modal-overlay absolute w-full h-full bg-gray-900 opacity-50 z-50"></div>

<div
  class="modal-container bg-white w-11/12 md:max-w-md mx-auto rounded shadow-lg z-50 overflow-y-auto"
>
  <div
    class="modal-close absolute top-0 right-0 cursor-pointer flex flex-col items-center mt-4 mr-4 text-white text-sm z-50"
  >
    <svg
      class="fill-current text-white"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="18"
      height="18"
      viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    >
      <path
        d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"
      />
    </svg>
    <span class="text-sm">(Esc)</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Add margin if you want to see some of the overlay behind the modal-->
  <div class="modal-content py-4 text-left px-6">
    <!--Title-->
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center pb-3">
      <p class="text-2xl font-bold">Bedankt</p>
      <div class="modal-close cursor-pointer z-50">
        <svg
          class="fill-current text-black"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="18"
          height="18"
          viewBox="0 0 18 18"
        >
          <path
            d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z"
          />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Body-->
    <p>Je email adres is toegevoegd aan onze mailing list. We houden je op de hoogte van de laatste ontwikkelingen</p>
    <p>Tevens hebben we je op de beta lijst gezet en je zult als een van de eersten een uitnodiging van ons ontvangen om het platform te testen</p>
    <!--Footer-->
    <div class="flex justify-end pt-2">
      <button
        @click="toggleModal"
        class="modal-close px-4 bg-indigo-500 p-3 rounded-lg text-white hover:bg-indigo-400"
      >Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made sure with a `console.log()` that the `click` events are added. However when I click on the modal nothing happens. I tried to do a `console.log()` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why use raw selectors and event listeners if you are using Vue?  Can you post enough HTML to reproduce the issue?

Comment: you need to use nextTick in mounted and then put your code inside nextTick function... read the docs to find out more

Comment: Because the events are added to a div and not to inputs or so. Will update the post soon

Comment: it is because you are adding click event to element that doesnt exist in dom yet

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/

Comment: Need to see more code. Show us the template, especially where the modal overlay is used.

Comment: I have updated my post with the template

Answer (score 1):

You can add click listeners to basically anything in Vue. That's the magic of it. It can be a div, a span, an image. Just add @click to your overlay div and it should work.

```
<div ref="overlay" @click="toggleModal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is the CSS class `pointer-events-none`. I don't know for sure what that does but assuming it adds `pointer-events: none` it would disable all click events for all child elements.

That should be sufficient to solve your problem, however I would also note that:

1. In Vue it is preferred to use `ref`/`$refs` instead of CSS selectors if you want to grab hold of elements inside the `mounted` hook.
2. The `mounted` hook should not be necessary as you can just add `@click` attributes directly in the template.
3. Be careful to ensure that you haven't added the click listener to any elements twice. I don't know what `toggleModal` does but there's a risk that if you call it twice you'll end up changing nothing. In the code you provided it seems that some elements were getting two click listeners, both pointing at `toggleModal`.